# Detect an icon in a chip label - react jest testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am working on a react/material UI app. Within one of my components, I create a bunch of `Chip`s by cycling through some maps (which is where the `index1`, `index2`, and `value` below come from). When a `Chip` is clicked, then a `StarRateIcon` is added to the label to indicate which `Chip` was last clicked - the state stores the `id` of the most recently clicked `Chip`. If a `Chip` is clicked again, the `StarRateIcon` goes away again. The following code highlights the relevant parts of what I am doing:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import StarRateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/StarRate';

export default function Example(){
    const [clickedKey, setClickedKey] = React.useState(null);

    return(
        ...
        <Chip 
            data-testid={`chip-${index1}-${index2}`}
            label={
                <span>
                    {value}
                    {clickedKey === `chip-${index1}-${index2}` ? <StarRateIcon /> : null}
                </span>
            }
            onClick={() => {
                setClickedKey(filterKey !== `chip-${index1}-${index2}` ? `chip-${index1}-${index2}` : null
            }}
        />
        ...
    );
}
```

I then wish to test that when a given `Chip` is clicked, that the `StarRateIcon` is visible in that `Chip`. The project is using `jest` so I need to do so too.

So far, I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import Example from '<path>/Example';

it('star icon is visible when chip is clicked', () {
    const { getByTestId } = render (
        <Example />
    );
    const chip = getByTestId('chip-0-0');
    fireEvent.click(chip);

    // TODO what next?
    // expect(chip). 
});
```

but I can't then work out what to `expect` at the end. If I use

```
expect(chip).toHaveTextContent(`example ${<StarRateIcon />}`)
```

then it fails as the `StarRateIcon` is not included in the text content. This is how I would do it if there were no `StarRateIcon` to consider, and indeed it works for all the chips which have not been clicked and are not displaying the `StarRateIcon`.

I also tried

```
expect(chip).toBe(`example ${<StarRateIcon />}`)
```

but that also didn't work.

I've done a bit of hunting and playing around with some of the other functions available on `expect` but none of them seem to flag up the existence of the `StarRateIcon`.

I'm very new to front end development and testing - can someone point me towards an acceptable way to accomplish this test please?

Answer (score 2):

Material ui icons have icon name as data-testid. This should work

```
expect(getByTestId('DeckSharpIcon')).toBeVisible();
```

```
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-1xkvp8t-MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="DeckSharpIcon"><path d="M22 9 12 2 2 9h9v13h2V9z"></path><path d="m4.14 12-1.96.37.82 4.37V22h2l.02-4H7v4h2v-6H4.9zm14.96 4H15v6h2v-4h1.98l.02 4h2v-5.26l.82-4.37-1.96-.37z"></path></svg>
```

if using FontAwesomeIcon:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationTriangle} data-testid="icon" />
```

```
expect(getByTestId('icon')).toHaveClass('svg-inline--fa fa-triangle-exclamation fa-3x');
```